# CSS appearance changes between page refreshes, on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, refresh

good afternoon,

i have a small bit of CSS that builds a decorative "ribbon" to hold the date for blog posts. it works fine, sometimes.

between refreshes it appears that the margins and positioning i set in the CSS occasionally get skipped.

this happens while hitting the "refresh" button on the same browser window of firefox. seemingly at random, whether shift-reload or regular is used.

[picture to show working/broken appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zZ3y.gif)

```css
body {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  
  color: #cfcfcf;
  background-color: #3b85a9;

  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif; } 

.ribbon1 {display:inline-block;width:100%;}

.ribbon2 {
 /*                                                                 */
 /* original from Ian Yates - http://tutsplus.com/authors/ian-yates */
 /*                                                                 */

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
   
    display:block;
    height: 60px;               /* width of the ribbon */
    width:25px;                 /* length of the ribbon */
    
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: 1px;
     
    background-color: #c94700; }

.ribbon2:after {            /* builds the folded edge */
    content: ""; 
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 0px;
     
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    z-index: 4;
     
    border-bottom: 60px solid #de6625;   
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;   
     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom; }
    
.ribbon2:before {       /* the shadow effect for the folded edge  */
    content: "";   
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 0px;
     
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
     
    border-bottom: 60px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);     
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;       
     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(85deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom; }
    
    
.blog_year {
 position: absolute;
 top:4;
 left:6;
    width: 0; 
 
 word-wrap: break-word;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 line-height: 0.95em; }

.blog_month {
 position: absolute;
 top:-20;
 left:24;
 width: 60px;
 z-index: 5;
  
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 line-height: 1em; }

.blog_day {
 position: absolute;
 top:-5;
 left:24;
 width: 60px;
 z-index: 5;
 
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 line-height: 1em;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }

.blog_title {
 width: 700px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-top: 5;
 clear:right;
 
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 2.5em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container" 
 style="width:500px; margin:50px; padding:10px; background:#444;">

 <div class="ribbon1">
  <div class="ribbon2"> 
   <span class="blog_year"> 2016 </span> 
   <span class="blog_month"> march </span> 
   <span class="blog_day"> 15 </span> 
   <div class="blog_title"> Here's your words. </div> 
  </div> <!-- div "ribbon2" -->
 </div> <!-- div "ribbon1" -->

</div>

</body>
```

i have seen other threads on here with similar issues, and the suggestion was that there was a chached version of the CSS. unfortunately, even on the first viewing of a test page, the CSS positioning was apparently ignored, until i hit "refresh". so there's no way it's a cache issue.

any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: You need to set units on your properties, i.e. `px`, as @Marvin shows in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why it works for you after refreshing. For me it only works if I fix the css and add the missing `px` units:

```
.blog_year {
    top:4px;
    left:6px;
}
.blog_month {
    top:-20px;
    left:24px;
}
.blog_day {
    top:-5px;
    left:24px;
}
.blog_title {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: what a shockingly obvious mistake to make, Marvin. thank you for pointing out my clearly self-inflicted problem :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: i'm embarassed to admit i could not find how to "Accept" an answer, or mark my question "Answered". i upvoted your answer. where is the link for accepting an answer???

Comment: There should be a [check right under the vote button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) :)